# Why I still cannot use fragment when using Eclipse(Android)?

Tags: java, android, tabs, fragment, swipe

First, I've upgraded to API-21 including eclipse android toolkit and SDK. 
I want to use the fragment feature and still want to support those 2.x phones
I know that I must use support library - v4.
But the problem is when I create an Android project, it always shows "Navigation Type "Scrollable Tabs + Swipe" requires a minimum SDK version of at least 11, and the current min version is 8". 
How could I solve this tricky problem?

======================================
My settings:
Minimum required SDK: API 8
Target SDK: API 17
Compile With: API 17

======================================

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse's project templates make use of features that require a number of APIs (mostly `ActionBar`), which are not provided by the support library. While you can use `Fragments`, with the support library, you don't have the other features associated with the APIs.

You could still implement swipe/scroll tabs by yourself though. However, you will have to create them manually (and **not** using Eclipse's built-in project templates).

You will need to use [android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTabStrip.html), [android.support.v4.view.ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) and [android.support.v4.app.Fragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html). The documentation is pretty clear and should point you in the right direction.